# NHibernate Get objects without proxy

Tags: c#, nhibernate, proxy-classes

I am using NHibernate(2.0.1.4) with NHibernate.Linq(1.0.0.4) to get Objects of the type Node from the Database.

When I get these objects, the last object of the collection I got is of the type Proxy (because I used "NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu""  )

I used the following linq query:

```
var mynodes = from node in session.Linq<Node>() where ancestorNodes.Contains(node.Id) select node).ToList()
```

anchestorNodes is a list of Id's for the node objects to get.

When I have 3 id's in the "ancestorNodes" list, the last object of the result (mynodes) I got from the query is of the type nodeProxy.

How could this be? 
Why is it always the last object?
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your Proxy object implements INhibernateProxy, you can unproxy the object with NHibernate with the following code:

```
iAmaSession.GetSessionImplementation().PersistenceContext.Unproxy(iAmaProxy)
```

Hope this helps!